# $M$ is inside the parallelogram $ABCD$. If $\angle MBA=\angle MDA$, then $\angle MAB = \angle MCB$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, angle

Let M be a point inside the parallelogram ABCD, such that $\angle MBA = \angle MDA$ . Prove that $\angle MAB = \angle MCB$.

Source: Romanian Mathematical Gazette no. 5/2023

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: One can solve it using complex representation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Draw a line through $M$ parallel to $AD$, $BC$ and draw a point $M'$ such that $MM'=AD=BC$, as on the picture above. This makes the quadrilaterals $AM'MD$ and $M'BCM$ parallelograms.

Thus, $\angle AM'M=\angle ADM=\angle ABM$ which implies that the quadrilateral $AM'BM$ is cyclic.

That in turn implies that $\angle BCM=\angle BM'M=\angle BAM$ (the last equality is implied by $AM'BM$ being cyclic).